# Lebesgue integrability of $e^{-x^2*e^{2*i*\phi }}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I would like to prove that 
$$f(x)=\exp{(-x^2\exp{(2i\phi)})}$$
Is in $\mathcal{L1}$ for $\phi\in(-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{4})$.

Exploiting the trigonometric identity for $\exp{(2i\phi)}$ did not help me.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $|e^{-x^{2}\exp2i\theta}|=|e^{-x^{2}(\cos 2\theta+i\sin 2\theta)}|=|e^{-x^{2}\cos 2\theta}|\cdot|e^{-x^{2}i\sin 2\theta}|=e^{-x^{2}\cos 2\theta}$, since $\theta\in(-\pi/4,\pi/4)$, $c:=\cos 2\theta>0$, then it is easy to see $e^{-cx^{2}}\in L^{1}(-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: Doesn't that imply $e^{-x^{2}i\sin 2\theta}=1$ ? If so, why can we conclude that?

Comment: It is the absolute value of $e^{-x^{2}i\sin 2\theta}$ is $1$.

Comment: $|e^{iu}|=|\cos u+i\sin u|=\sqrt{(\cos u)^{2}+(\sin u)^{2}}=1$.

Comment: And with the integral being finite, the proof is complete.
$e^{-cx^{2}}<\infty\Rightarrow e^{-cx^{2}}\in L^{1}(-\infty,\infty) $

Comment: The implication is not true: A function with everywhere finite value does not implies that it is integrable, take for example $f(x)=x^{2}$. Rather, for the case of $e^{-cx^{2}}$, it is an even function, it suffices to deal with the interval $[0,\infty)$. By scalar multiplication transformation, it suffices to deal with $c=1$. In such a case it has no singularity (and bounded) on $[0,1)$, so it suffices to look at the interval $[1,\infty)$, but $e^{-x^{2}}\leq e^{-x}$ on $[1,\infty)$ and $\displaystyle\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx=e^{-1}<\infty$.